# Rails - (Devise) Single sign up for multiple user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to databases and I am creating a web application using rails.

In this web app, there are 3 types of Users which have varying levels of access within the app.

So I was wondering if it is possible to have a single Sign Up (using Devise) and have 1 field wherein the selection would indicate what user type the account is signing up for?

Comment: Do you want the users to self-assign an account type or assign it for them based on something else?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone I want them to self-assign upon sign-up